# HTML code not working in kolkov/angular-editor while use in Angular editor

Tags: angular, typescript, html-editor, kolkov-editor

I am using below editor in my angular application.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor

**Issue is** : When loading a page the editor UI works as expected, but any action that alters the contents of the text box while the HTML Code View is active breaks the menu buttons for the editor. The only way reset the functionality is to reload the page.

For more info please see this link : [Issue description](https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor/issues/270)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `sanitize` is `true` in the angular editor. We need to disable sanitization by setting the option `sanitize` to `false` in your config object to work with Html.

```
config: AngularEditorConfig = {
    ....
    sanitize: false,
    ....
  };
}
```

**Demo link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editor-wysiwyg-i-4tyml5